# How to make a string in javascript become incasesensitive?

Tags: javascript

SOMEBODY help me out

Exercise: Write a function indexOfIgnoreCase, that accepts two strings and determines the first
occurrence of the second string in the first
string. The function should be case insensitive. `indexOfIgnoreCase("bit","it")` and `indexOfIgnoreCase("bit","IT")` should return 1.

THIS IS WHAT I GOT.. It is working fine.. The problem now is to make it INCASESENSITIVE

```
var indexOfIgnoreCase=function(x,y){
  return x.indexOf(y);
  var output=indexOfIgnoreCase("bit","it");
  return indexOfIgnoreCase.toUpperCase(); 
}
```

Comment: How about lowercase everything before checking?

Comment: It looks like you have a function with more than one return value. I edited the code to make it readable, but you might want to edit it so the code makes sense. Also, the all-caps aren't helpful.

Comment: Guys please give reason before down voting. (Might help him, like what this site is all about you know...)

Comment: @1010101 What more to say than the tooltip of the downvote button? _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ (ignoring the missing formatting and the unnecessary screaming)

Comment: This line `return indexOfIgnoreCase.toUpperCase(); ` <-- makes no sense. It is do toUpperCase on a function? So reason you are not just doing `return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(y.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question definitely has some quality problems, but here is the solution:

```
let indexOfIgnoreCase = function(x, y) {
    return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(y.toLowerCase());
}
```

Are you still learning JavaScript? The first statement in your code already returns from the entire function, so you got a bunch of dead code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regular expressions

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/search
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split

Comment: He wants to do a case-insensitive match and return an index. Why does he need "to know if it IS in lowercase"?